# invoke cmd in winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to find all the files matching `*.XMODEL_EXPORT` and automatically convert them to .BIN format.

Here's the code i have so far.

```
public DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls.RichTextBoxEx richTextBoxEx1;

public static string path { get; set; }

public static string mainpath { get; set; }

public bo3_bincs(DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls.RichTextBoxEx elfenliedtofan5txt)
{
    richTextBoxEx1 = elfenliedtofan5txt;
}

public void check64()
{
    if(mainpath == null)
    {
        string programFilesX86 = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%");
        mainpath = programFilesX86;
    }
    else
    {
        string programFiles = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramW6432%");
        mainpath = programFiles;
    }
}

public void findpath()
{
    if (path == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(mainpath);
        string elfenlied = mainpath + @"/aaa/";
        string[] oDirectories = Directory.GetFiles(elfenlied, "*.XMODEL_EXPORT", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string oCurrent in oDirectories) 
            richTextBoxEx1.Text = oCurrent;
    }
    else
    {

    }
}

public void convertbin()
{
    path = mainpath + "//aaa//";
    MessageBox.Show(path);
    Process bin = new Process();
    bin.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    bin.StartInfo.Arguments = "cd " + path;
    bin.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    bin.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    //bin.StartInfo.Arguments = path;
    //bin.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    //bin.StartInfo.Arguments = "rename *.**.bin";
    bin.Start();
    richTextBoxEx1.Text = bin.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I want it to convert all the files from the specified folder, but it's just defaulting to the directory below the Visual Studio Debug folder.

Answer (score 0):

StartInfo has a [WorkingDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) property that you can set to your desidered path. But remember, if you launch cmd.exe without /C or /K it exits immediately without executing your command arguments. Add /C or /K to your StartInfo.Arguments (better /K to see the result of your efforts)

```
    path = mainpath + "//aaa//";
    MessageBox.Show(path);
    Process bin = new Process();
    bin.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    bin.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
    //bin.StartInfo.Arguments = "cd " + path;
    bin.StartInfo.Arguments = "/K dir";
```

Comment: thank you ever so much that worked perfectly just have to find out how to get it to work now with the convert process because i cmd can convert a file to .bin just need to work it out not sure how at the moment